# How do I get ISSNs and full journal names from a list of abbreviated journal names in R?

Tags: r, medical, pubmed, journal

I have a list of research journals that I have extracted from iCite and pubmed, but they only give me the abbreviated journal names. How do I get the full names and ISSNs?

```
 [1] Nat Commun                    Cancer Cell                  
 [`your text`3] Clin Cancer Res               Nature                       
 [5] N Engl J Med                  J Clin Oncol                 
 [7] Cancer Discov                 Nat Med                      
 [9] Cancer Res                    Nat Rev Cancer               
[11] Cell                          Nat Rev Clin Oncol           
[13] Nat Rev Dis Primers           Nat Cancer                   
[15] J Immunother Cancer           Sci Rep                      
[17] Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A      Blood                        
[19] Science                       Cancer                       
[21] JAMA Oncol                    Cell Rep                     
[23] J Clin Invest                 Front Immunol                
[25] Lancet Oncol                  JAMA Netw Open               
[27] Nat Rev Mol Cell Biol         Nat Rev Gastroenterol Hepatol
[29] Nat Genet                     Oncogene                     
[31] Ann Oncol                     Nat Immunol                  
[33] Mol Cell                      Leukemia                     
[35] Sci Transl Med                J Hepatol                    
[37] Blood Cancer J                J Thorac Oncol               
[39] J Natl Cancer Inst            Cancer Lett` `          
`

I want to convert this list to issns and full journal titles
```

Comment: Which ressource are you planning to use for the abbreviations lookup?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out using the pubmed database and entrez. By using the abbreviated journal name as a search term followed by "[TA]".

Going to answer my question here to help anyone in the future out:

```
journal_info <- function (top_journal) {
    search_term <- paste(top_journal, "[TA]")
    journal_query <- entrez_search(db="pubmed", term=search_term)
    id <- journal_query$ids[1]
    summary_result <- entrez_summary(db = "pubmed", id = id)
    issn <- summary_result$issn
    title <- summary_result$fulljournalname
    j_info <- data.frame(issn,title)
    j_info
}
```